# Calculating shipping costs and tax with Stripe

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, tax

I'm using Stripe with Laravel 5.4. My problem here is that I was asked to include the shipping costs and the taxes to the total amount when using Stripe. Payments are possible in USA only.

Is that possible to do in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe does not have an API for calculating taxes and shipping costs. You'd need to use another API for this. You can see some recommendations here:

- https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/shipping
- https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/tax-calculation

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I will look into each one of those, and come out with an explanation which worked best. And yes, my client would appreciate if I don't use a paid service.